# Ribbons to secure lenses in a camera bag

Tags: camera-bag

What's the name of those ribbons with velcro that help secure the lenses in a camera bag, as in the picture below? I'd like to buy some, but have no clue how are they called.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s just Velcro, and completely unnecessary Velcro. I’ve had that exact pack fully loaded without the straps and have never had an issue.

But, if you insist, just get some bulk Velcro and cut to size: [16 Feet Length 0.75 Inch Width Hook and Loop with Strong Self Adhesive Tape Strip Fastener (White)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XQ5FTC2) (Amazon.com)